# How to retrieve data in the same order as the subquery?

Tags: sql, oracle

Let us say Employee and Shippers tables have following data.

```
EmployeeID  Name    
1           Davolio 
2           Fuller  
3           Leverling   
4           Peacock 
5           Buchanan
6           Suyama  
7           King    
8           Callahan
9           Dodsworth
10          West

ShipperID   ShipperName 
1           Speedy Express  
2           United Package  
3           Federal Shipping
```

The below query returns ShipperID in descending order.

```
select ShipperID from Shippers order by ShipperID desc;
```

Now, I want to retrieve Names from the Employee table in the same order the ShipperID's are retrieved (`3,2,1`). My expected output is `Leverling, Fuller, Davolio`.

```
select Name from Employee where EmployeeID in (select ShipperID from Shippers order by ShipperID desc)
```

The above query is not returning the data as I expect. How to fix this?

UPDATE:
This is not about the ordering of records in ascending or descending order. This is just an example I have posted here. To make it more clear, assume that the subquery is returning ShipperID as `2,3,1`. Now I want to retrieve the records from Employee table like `Fuller, Leverling, Davolio`

Comment: I'm suprised the query even runs. Why do you need the `in` ordered? You only want to see if the `EmployeeID` is present, the order doesn't matter. If you want your results ordered, you should order your outer query

Answer (score 3):

You will have to join the two tables if you want to keep the ordering. The order in the subquery is not preserved if you use `IN`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select distinct Employee.Name from Employee 
inner join Shippers on Shippers.ShipperID=Employee.EmployeeID
order by Shippers.ShipperID desc
```

Comment: Just that it will be a error due to the DISTINCT and ORDER BY not in sync, other wise this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
select Name from Employee where EmployeeID in (select ShipperID from Shippers ) order by ShipperID desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Name from Employee where EmployeeID in (select ShipperID from Shippers ) order by EmployeeID desc
```

as employeeid=shipperid you can order by employeeid

Answer (score 0):

If you want results to appear in a particular order, then you're going to have to pick something to order by. In your example, this means adding a column to define the order of the shippers and then joining that back to the employees table, so that you can then order the employee results accordingly.

Something like:

```
WITH employees AS (SELECT 1 employeeid, 'Davolio' NAME FROM dual UNION ALL
                   SELECT 2 employeeid, 'Fuller' NAME FROM dual UNION ALL
                   SELECT 3 employeeid, 'Leverling' NAME FROM dual UNION ALL
                   SELECT 4 employeeid, 'Peacock' NAME FROM dual UNION ALL
                   SELECT 5 employeeid, 'Buchanan' NAME FROM dual),
      shippers AS (SELECT 1 shipperid, 'Speedy Express' shippername FROM dual UNION ALL
                   SELECT 2 shipperid, 'United Package' shippername FROM dual UNION ALL
                   SELECT 3 shipperid, 'Federal Shipping' shippername FROM dual)
-- end of mimicking your tables, see SQL below:
SELECT emp.employeeid,
       emp.name
FROM   employees emp
       INNER JOIN (SELECT shipperid,
                          CASE WHEN shipperid = 1 THEN 3
                               WHEN shipperid = 2 THEN 1
                               WHEN shipperid = 3 THEN 2
                          END order_id
                   FROM   shippers) shp ON emp.employeeid = shp.shipperid
ORDER BY shp.order_id ASC;

EMPLOYEEID NAME
---------- ---------
         2 Fuller
         3 Leverling
         1 Davolio
```

Your order_id column may be something that already exists (e.g. a timestamp column) or generated (either by an explicit case statement as I demonstrated above, or by using the `row_number()` analytic function) but if you want your results to appear in a particular order, you need that column.